# Python logging level based on variable value?

Tags: python, logging

I need to change the logging level based on the value of a variable.  For example:

```
if accel >= 10.0:
    log_func = logging.critical # Critical for splat event
elif accel >= 2.0:
    log_func = logging.warning  # Warning for high-G
elif accel >= 1.0:
    log_func = logging.info     # Info for normal
else:
    log_func = logging.debug    # Debug otherwise
log_func("Collision with %0.1fG impact.", accel)
```

I have instances of this all through my code.  Is there a better way?

Comment: You always end up with either `logging.info` or `logging.debug` with that logic. Because when `accel >= 10.0` is True, so is `accel >= 2.0`. You want to use `elif` instead of `if` for all but the first test.

Comment: Thanks!  I goofed editing actual code down to minimal example.  Fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the `Logger.log()` method instead, and pass in a level constant:

```
import sys

# Map accel values to log levels
levels = (
    (10.0, logging.CRITICAL),
    (2.0, logging.WARNING), 
    (1.0, logging.INFO),
    (-sys.maxsize, logging.DEBUG)
)

logging.log(next(lev[1] for lev in levels if lev[0] <= accel),
    "Collision with %0.1fG impact.", accel)
```

You could encapsulate the level selection into a utility function:

```
def level_for_accel(accel):
    # return next matching log level for the given accel value
    return next(lev[1] for lev in levels if lev[0] <= accel)

logging.log(level_for_accel(accel), "Collision with %0.1fG impact.", accel)
```

Log levels are really integers, and the `CRITICAL`, `WARNING`, etc. values are merely constants. There are any number of ways you can turn one value (e.g. `accel`) into a matching log level with a few simple rules, in a more readable manner than a large number of `if` / `else` branches.

Comment: I like the idea of using logging.log(), but the above adds visual and execution complexity for no improvements in space or clarity.  But this does make it clear that I'm actually binning the data, and logging is only a result.  I suppose I need a classifier for the data, and a generic log wrapper that maps classifications to log levels.

Comment: @user1366715: The `next()` call can easily be encapsulated in a function of course. The point is more that you not select a logging convenience function, but that you only pick a log *level* instead.

Comment: This is certainly the right direction. I'd like to avoid explicitly mixing values and log levels in 'levels' (gets old after many uses), and have a generic log heirarchy that's universal.  Perhaps pass a single tuple (accel, (10.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0))?

Comment: I'm going to flag this as the answer, since it is the best approach, though I'll need to experiment a bit until I find what works best for my particular needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could create a function which takes the variable accel and returns the appropriate logging function. and then call that. It would probably be cleaner and more maintainable code. Not to mention DRY.

```
def logger(accel):
    if accel >= 10.0:
        return logging.critical # Critical for splat event
    if accel >= 2.0:
        return logging.warning  # Warning for high-G
    if accel >= 1.0:
       return logging.info     # Info for normal
   else:
       return logging.debug    # Debug otherwise
```

Then you could use it as

```
logger(12)("hello world")
```

Comment: True, but since it's one-off code, I'm looking for a higher-level template, rather than adding the overhead of a function call.